# How to create numpy boolean 2darray based on the argmin of another numpy 2darray?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix

I have a masked 2d array with numpy that looks a bit like this:

```
1.73 2.48 -- 9.80 --
4.98 2.01 -- 3.81 --
2.35 4.53 -- 2.45 --
6.54 8.43 -- 2.13 --
8.45 4.58 -- 2.49 --
```

I want a resulting 2darray which has `True` for the minimum non-masked values of each row and `False` for the rest. So:

```
True False -- False --
False True -- False --
True False -- False --
False False -- True --
False False -- True --
```

I've tried doing `a == a.min()` but this doesn't seem to work due to the masked numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This ought to do it for you, and I believe it is general enough for non-square arrays and for arrays with irregular masks.

```
data = [[i == j for j in range(a.shape[-1])] for i in a.argmin(axis=1)]
result = np.ma.masked_array(data=data, mask=a.mask)
```

If you don't need the mask on `result`, you can simply use `data` instead.